# php step by step execution

Tags: php, debugging

I am trying to explore PHP.For every programming language debugger is an useful tool.Through some search i found out that Xdebug is a good tool.Can any one help me out wat tool i must use to see the values of variable or step by step execution...

Thanks in advance

Comment: m really new to this...m not getting wat u mean

Comment: From the FAQ: "When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer." 
http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Eclipse with [PHP Development Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/). It contains support for XDebug and step-bystep debugging.